# tun0 not working after configuring openvpn

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, openvpn, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to get Internet access after configuring my openvpn client but I can't accomplish it. This is how I'm doing:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/US\ East.ovpn >> /home/javi/log_file.log 2>&1 &
```

This is what I have in **US\ East.ovpn**

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote us-east.privateinternetaccess.com 1198
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
cipher aes-128-cbc
auth sha1
tls-client
remote-cert-tls server
auth-user-pass
comp-lzo
verb 1
reneg-sec 0
crl-verify /etc/openvpn/crl.rsa.2048.pem
ca /etc/openvpn/ca.rsa.2048.crt
disable-occ
auth-user-pass /etc/openvpn/piaauth.txt
```

after running the above command my ifconfig looks like this (enp3s0 is my eth0):

```
enp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr bc:ae:--:--:--:--  
      inet addr:192.168.1.128  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::2970:1589:8ab:6f86/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:240340 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:126235 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:353873769 (353.8 MB)  TX bytes:9924327 (9.9 MB)
      Interrupt:40 

lo    ......

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
      inet addr:10.137.1.6  P-t-P:10.137.1.5  Mask:255.255.255.255
      UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:24 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:1247 (1.2 KB)
```

route table

```
    Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.134.1.5      128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp3s0
10.134.1.1      10.134.1.5      255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun0
10.134.1.5      *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
128.0.0.0       10.134.1.5      128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp3s0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp3s0
209.222.23.61   192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 enp3s0
```

traceroute 8.8.8.8

```
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.146.1.1 (10.146.1.1)  117.873 ms  118.239 ms  118.244 ms
 2  107.191.35.233 (107.191.35.233)  119.045 ms  119.246 ms  119.466 ms
 3  108.61.92.205 (108.61.92.205)  119.241 ms  120.030 ms  120.033 ms
 4  66.55.144.145 (66.55.144.145)  145.257 ms  127.335 ms  145.301 ms
 5  198.32.160.130 (198.32.160.130)  122.537 ms 72.14.214.16 (72.14.214.16)  122.541 ms  123.544 ms
 6  209.85.246.223 (209.85.246.223)  123.656 ms 108.170.234.11 (108.170.234.11)  121.911 ms 216.239.63.95 (216.239.63.95)  119.989 ms
 7  108.170.235.27 (108.170.235.27)  120.361 ms 108.170.235.21 (108.170.235.21)  120.443 ms 108.170.233.243 (108.170.233.243)  121.028 ms
 8  8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8)  120.421 ms  121.028 ms  121.029 ms
```

Comment: Why are you already configuring firewall rules if you haven't yet got the connection working?  Disable the firewall, remove those unneeded details from the question, and show us your routing table and troubleshooting with the VPN connection active.

Comment: @JuliePelletier there you have it. Thanks for your help

Comment: I just noticed that your `tun0` transmitted 24 packets but received none.  This most likely indicates that the problem is on the other side of the VPN.  Are other clients able to use this connection?

Comment: Well the thing is that I've already "pinged" 8.8.8.8 and it's working. Maybe it's a DNS problem, right?

Comment: Check if `traceroute 8.8.8.8` really goes through the tunnel.  I doubt it.

Comment: Yes it is going through the tunnel (tun ip changes every time I connect)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44547/discussion-between-javipedrera-and-julie-pelletier).

Comment: Then your assumption on it being a DNS problem is quite obvious now.  You should change your system's DNS configuration to `8.8.8.8` which would work with and without the VPN.

Comment: All working adding a DNS server in resolv.conf now :)

Answer (score 1):

A common problem with the Internet connection when using a VPN is domain name resolution.

The simplest solution is to set up a public DNS server globally.  This can be done by putting the following in `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```